# Retrospectively deactivate APKs in Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I had a release on the google play console that had a bug. The release was rolled out to only 1% of users. The bug was fixed, and I rolled out a new version. However in the new version, I only elected to deactivate the previous build which has been released to 1% of users. I believe I should have also elected to deactivate the previous build that all users were using. It looks like this has resulted in only the faulty build being updated to the new version, whereas I'd like all users to be updated to the new version (if they have auto update enabled).

I think I could fix this by doing a new release and deactivating the previous build and the build before that. But ideally I'd be able to do this without a new release. Is there a way to tell the play console to retrospectively serve the latest release to all users when they update? Or can it only be done when creating a new release?